# JDBC Sink Configuration Options batch.size

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

From https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html#jdbc-sink-configuration-options

```
Specifies how many records to attempt to batch together for insertion into the destination table, when possible.

Type: int
Default: 3000
Valid Values: [0,…]
Importance: medium
```

> So, this is from Confluent site.
>
> Importance is medium, default is 3000. What if I want the KAFKA
>   changes every 30 secs even if there are say, only 27 KAFKA messages
>   for the topic? What is default setting in which processing occurs on a
>   per elapsed time basis? We all know this is catered for as we can run many examples just passing 1 records from, say mySQL to SQLServer, but I cannot find the parameter value for time based processing. Can I influence it?

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/290    Noted this as well. Some interesting stuff there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should focus on the words "when possible"

`consumer.max.poll.records` will always grab up to that many records from Kafka. Once a poll is complete, the JDBC sink will build as many batches as needed until the next consumer poll is called within `consumer.max.poll.interval.ms`

Comment: So, in the yellow box I note the situation of a single record. What you are saying is that there seems to be a tie in with the Topic from both sides. That makes sense and empirical observation tells me that as well. I cannot tell the KAFKA Connect Sink to poll the topic every minute then.

Comment: I noted in that 2nd URL the question on 449 recs out of 500 batch size. Completely wrong.

Comment: The consumer polls as frequently as it would in a plain consumer loop. Connect isn't a solution for batch consumption

Comment: We need near real time, so I think that is fine. We have spark kafka integration for data lake, batch mode.

Comment: HDFS Sink connector work fine for that use case as well, by the way

Comment: true, but we do some processing as in versioning, history.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/creates-a-cdc-stream-from-oracle-database-to-kafka  following this approach

Comment: Sure, GoldenGate/Debezium are sources. What you do with that data once it is in Kafka could be anything. For example, you could use Kafka Streams to filter the incoming CDC records into a format suitable for the datalake, then use Connect sink to write them out differently. Then you don't really need a Spark cluster