# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Commits

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I cannot find the commit strategy or a parameter for Kafka Connect JDBC Sink in terms of that JDBC target.

Is it commit every `N` rows or when `batch.size` reached? Whatever that `N` rows is? Batch size or when complete would make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC Sink Configuration Options batch.size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802345/jdbc-sink-configuration-options-batch-size)

Comment: If I wasn't clear in that answer, I could have editted. And the code is open source, so you could poke around in it

Comment: many other things to do. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Kafka Connect worker is running a sink task, it [will consume](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/d755ca14a05550480e3c9eba36846aafdb5a06fd/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L224) messages from the topic partition(s) assigned to the task: once partitions have been opened for writing, Connect will begin forwarding records from Kafka using the [put(Collection)](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkTask.html#put-java.util.Collection-) API.

JDBC sink connector writes each batch of messages passed through the [put(Collection)](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkTask.html#put-java.util.Collection-) method using a [transaction](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/f05b616492dd933bd4afdc3acd6181ba18fd62fd/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/sink/JdbcDbWriter.java#L75) (the size of which can be controlled via the connector's consumer settings).

Comment: Right, but what is the relevance of batch.size then? Seem to member the source, consumer stuff all being a little different.

Comment: Do you mean the producer `batch.size` property?

Comment: Yes, indeed, Sir.

Comment: You can absolutely not worry about producers or source connector tasks since sink connector doesn't need to know about them (just about Kafka topic)

Comment: Sink connector **does** care about `consumer.*` properties... E.g. you can set `consumer.max.poll.records` and `consumer.auto.offset.reset` cc @theblue

Comment: @cricket_007  seems tightly coupled. kafka prod & cons seem independent otherwise.

Comment: @theblue Coupled in what way? Kafka Connect is just a high-level wrapper around consumer and producer APIs with a Struct + Schema definition

Comment: @cricket_007  But with |Spark Str Streaming and Spark KAFKA integration I can run when I want. Connect Sink seems less able to do its own thing, I get your point as well, and know the point about batch.size from you, but ... wrapper includes both yes... somehow I think u understand my point as well. I cannot say in Sink Connector commit every 25 rows

Comment: @theblue Not sure what you mean "run when [you] want". Spark is still running in "microbatches", and still uses the same consumer settings and JDBC drivers that Connect would

Comment: @cricket_007   OK, that point is valid indeed, I may well have overlooked due to the fact that there is always the talk of writing to topics and then process when needed, etc. Point taken.

Comment: @cricket_007  In any event, reading some of this stuff on the internet is hard yakka as in not really clear. U have just calrified a point I was wondering on and taklking o some folks in the past about.

Comment: @cricket_007  I am grateful and every day we get a little better...